# opengl glRasterPos*() changes arguments

Tags: opengl

This is a part of my code and it's result in opengl/c++(using visual studio 2013):

```
GLint *raspos = new GLint[];

glRasterPos2i(56, 56);

glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, raspos);

cout << " , X : " << raspos[0] << " and " << " Y : " << raspos[1];
```

result

> X : 125 and  Y : 125

i can't understand what's going on! why glRasterPos2i changes the arguments ?

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates passed to glRasterPos are subject to the transformation pipeline. The values you retrieve is the raster position in window coordinates after undergoing those transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Because the raster position is transform by the current projection and modelview matrices just like an ordinary vertex is, but querying `GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION` is retrieving the *window space* coordinates.